# jquery datepicker codebehind issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have inherited a site and it is using the `JQuery` `datepicker`. When the `datepicker` text box is selected and the picker shows up, it is static (sometimes) until you click somewhere else on the site. After clicking elsewhere, you are able to select a date. Also, in the case that the `datepicker` works, when it first appears, if you select prev or next, it will jump to NOV. 1899.

Here is my code (it is the codebehind `C#`, also I'm not too familiar with `JQuery`):

```
StringBuilder jqDatePicker = new StringBuilder("$(document).ready(function () { $('#" + txtPurchaseDate.ClientID + "').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', maxDate: '0' }); });");
jqDatePicker.Append("var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();");
jqDatePicker.Append(" prm.add_endRequest(function() { $('#" + txtPurchaseDate.ClientID + "').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', maxDate: '0' }); });");
RegisterClientStartupScript("jqDatePicker", jqDatePicker.ToString());
```

Comment: This makes me love MVC Razor

Comment: Try running your code without the page request manager (lines 2 + 3). Do you still have the same problems? (I suspect this might break other functionality on the page)